# How to include Authorization header using Swagger in .NET Core 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I was used to use swagger in older versions of .NET Core. However, now using .NET Core 6, I'm not being able to add Authorization header using Authorize button in swagger.

How could I do this?

I already added this to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc(API_VERSION, new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = PROJECT_NAME,
        Version = API_VERSION
    });

    var xmlFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + XML_EXTENSION;
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

    c.AddSecurityDefinition(SECURITY_TYPE, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = SECURITY_DESCRIPTION,
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = SECURITY_HEADER_NAME,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = SECURITY_TYPE
    });

    c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});
```

and this:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint(SWAGGERFILE_PATH, PROJECT_NAME + API_VERSION);
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it's not too late, and if it is, that this answer might help others. Ran into the same problem today and finally found a Spanish post that pointed me to the right direction.

[ASP.NET: Dscribiendo una API con OpenAPI y Swagger](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/asp-net-describiendo-una-api-utilizando-openapi-swagger.aspx)

All you have to do is add an OpenApiSecurityRequirement via c.AddSecurityRequirement, which contains a second OpenApiSecurityScheme.

In my case, we use a JWT authorization bearer, but I think this may work for you as well.

This is my AddSwaggerGen and now it works the same as it does in .NET 5.

```cs
     builder?.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
     {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Internal", Version = "v2" });
        // Bearer token authentication
        OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            Description = "Specify the authorization token",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        };
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityDefinition);
            
        //New code to work with .NET6
        //I've splitted in two parts for better reading
        OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
        OpenApiSecurityScheme secondSecurityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        };
        securityRequirement.Add(secondSecurityDefinition, new string[] { });
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
        //End of new code
        
        
    });
```

Paste the token into the Authorize button, and if a control method needs authorization, Swagger will put it in the header.

Other pages that helped me understand this:

[Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters)

Look at "Changes from OpenAPI 2.0":
[Swagger Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/)

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked me in .NET 6. Setting token from "Authorize" button, I'm able to retrieve the token in a controller action using this:

```var bearerToken = Helper.GetBearerToken(Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString());```